# Show data markers on highstock navigator/timeline

Tags: highcharts, timeline, navigator

I'm using this timeline feature - http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/241/

I'd like the data points to be visible, and also support a hover functionality. Is this do-able? Right now, I just see an area chart, but would like to enhance it to display data points.

```
navigator: {
series: {
data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4],               
marker: {
enabled: true
}
}
},
```

Thanks,

Vikas.

Comment: So you need a tooltip on points or any other action ?

Comment: yes, a tooltip on points. And for the points to be visible instead of just an area chart.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not available, the tooltip is supported only in the plotarea, not navigator.